# How to hide a section in visualforce page onchange of picklist element

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a visual force page which contain a picklist with values 'yes' and 'no' and there is another section which contain a number of fields. So what is required is that on yes ,the section appears and on 'no' the section is hidden.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using [`actionSupport`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) that triggers on the change of the picklist and rerenders the output panel. The ouput panel only shows if the picklist value is not null and is equals to "yes" ([formula required](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)). Here is a simple example of how you can implement this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!object.MyPickList__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                        rerender="MyPanel"/>
</apex:inputField>

<apex:outputPanel id="MyPanel">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(object.MyPickList__c)) && 
                                     ISPICKVAL(object.MyPickList__c, 'yes'),true,false)}">
        ...
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: does ` ISPICKVAL(object.MyPickList__c, 'yes'),true,false)}">` work? I have `ISPICKVAL(Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c, 'High')` and get an error:  "Save error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text"

Comment: Brilliant solution. thanks a lot!