# On Visual Force Page I want to load Pageblock section if the Pick list value is selected yes on the same page?

Tags: visualforce, ajax

I want to load one page block section on the same VF Page only after the user select the value in the Picklist(which is on the same VFPage). I have used render and reRender option but it does not work for me as I guess that needs value submitted first for the picklist and than after it can affect.

I am creating VFPage for opportunity edit Screen. So I want user to only add date in certain fields if the previous pick-list is selected as yes.

I have also refered to this post here [How to hide a section in visualforce page onchange of picklist element](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22879/how-to-hide-a-section-in-visualforce-page-onchange-of-picklist-element)

but it is not loading page block section after I change the picklist value to yes. It seems I will required to do this through AJAX. but I don't know how.

Can anyone please help with this ?

My code snippet

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" extensions="Opp_edit" id="page" tabStyle="Opportunity" action="{!doLoad}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
 <apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                       <apex:outputLabel value="Electricity" for="Elec"/>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Electricity__c}" id="OppElectricity">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SectionID" id="AS"/>
                       </apex:inputField>
                   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  

 <apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="SectionB" columns="2"  id="SectionID" rendered="{! opportunity.Electricity__c=='yes'}">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You need to add `<apex:actionSupport>` to the picklist field that will submit the changed value to the controller using AJAX and will also re-Render the page block section.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have developed. It will be helpful in understanding the behaviour and resolving the issue.

Comment: I have added my code snippet which gives Idea what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @AAU I have already used actionsupprt at the picklist have a look at my code snippet which I have just now added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jquery to do this, so you can remove that. It should be a simple matter of :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" id="page" tabStyle="Opportunity">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" id="OppElectricity" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SectionID"/>
          </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:outputPanel id="SectionID" >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Opportunity.StageName == 'Prospecting',True,False)}">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="SectionB" columns="2" >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 1</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 2</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 3</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Unless you're trying to have only certain fields in the section display, instead. You'd still put the rerender on the outputpanel, but you'd want to set the rendered on the actual section items.

Comment: Hi Adam

Thanks for your answer, I have already done exact same thing.But changing the value of picklist does not change display the block .  Also I am comparing value by this way rendered="{! opportunity.Electricity__c=='yes'} because ISPICKVAL() does not work either. It gives another error Called expecting pickval, raceived text . DO you think that could cause problem?

Comment: Are you sure about: 

1) Location of the outputpanel closure
2) The Capitalization of the Picklist Text?

Comment: Ya. I even have double checked now. And Both of them is the same way as in your code.

Comment: Picklist Capitalization Does match with the value of picklist

Comment: I also want to clarify, what i am trying to achieve here, I simply want one page block on the visual force edit page to load for user in which they can enter values for the fields displayed, when Picklist value is yes, this picklist is also on the same page, I haven't done this in past. That's why I wanted to confirm this again?

Comment: I found the issue. We need two output panels - one that is the target of the re render, and one with the conditional render logic. I've updated the code sample to one that works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work. The code above is perfectly working fine. But it was not working on the page I wanted it to work, after so many try and error I have found out that in order for this to work all the required field in the page block section needs to have value. Then and only then rerender will trigger and unhide the section. 

is there any work around for this that you know? I want it to work regardless of required fields fill or not. 

Once again I would like to really thank you for writing this code.

Comment: Ah - the fact that there were required fields is new. In that case,  try putting <apex:actionRegion> tags around the the input field with the actionsupport.

Comment: Hey @adam Spot On ! That solved the problem too. Excellent work .

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Add `apex:outputPanel` above `apex:pageBlockSection` and `reRender outputpanel` when Selection options is changed.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" extensions="Opp_edit" id="page" tabStyle="Opportunity" action="{!doLoad}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Electricity" for="Elec"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Electricity__c}" id="OppElectricity">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SectionID" id="AS"/>
                </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:outputPanel id="SectionID">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="SectionB" columns="2"  rendered="{! opportunity.Electricity__c=='yes'}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I cannot wrap up <apex:pageBlockSection> in   <apex:outputPanel id="SectionID"></apex:outputPanel> as it gives following error The element type <apex:pageblocksection> must be terminated by the matching end-tag </apex:pageblocksection>

Comment: My bad the `<apex:pageBlockSection title="SectionB" columns="2"  rendered="{! opportunity.Electricity__c=='yes'}"/>` was not closed. Please see the updated code now.

Comment: Closing that tab resolved the error. but it is by default hiding the pageblock section title only and not entire section with the fields. Fields are still visible and merged with the previous page block. IS it working at your end? Did you test?

Comment: Changing the picklist value of Electricity__c to yes does not make it visible either