# Salesforce function ISPICKLIST error

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I am working on visual force pages for my custom object **Request_for_System_Change__c**.

There is a *Yes/No* picklist called `Request_Priority__c`

When this is *Yes* I want to show the field `Reason_for_High_priority__c` so the user can explain why the request is high priority.

Here below is the code:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c }">  
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange"    rerender="MyPanel"/>                                        
</apex:inputField>

<apex:outputPanel id="MyPanel">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c)) 
&& ISPICKVALRequest_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c, 'High'),true,false)}">

<apex:outputLabel value="reason for High Priority: "/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Reason_for_High_priority__c }"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

But I am getting an error when saving:

> Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text

so what am I doing wrong?

**NOTE**:
I have taken the above code from the answer given by mast0r [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22879/how-to-hide-a-section-in-visualforce-page-onchange-of-picklist-element)

Comment: I think there's a syntax issue in the code above, because the ISPICKVAL does not have an open bracket. Also, can you paste the controller code, please? Is the name of your property 'Request_for_System_Change__c'? That's a bit confusing

Comment: Try: `ISPICKVAL(Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c, 'High')` (assuming that the field `Request_Priority__c` is a picklist field)

Comment: is there anything wrong in my code that would cause the input field `Reason_for_High_Priority` to show regardless of the value in the picklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you handle a picklist value on a Visualforce page using the

```
!{Record__c.Field__c}
```

merge style syntax, since about 2009, it actually delivers the value as a string, not a picklist "object", the object is only delivered to the inputField/outputField widgets.

So all you need to do is:

```
rendered="{! NOT(ISBLANK(Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c)) 
&& Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c == 'High'}"
```

I have a feeling that can be simplified somehow too.. looks like a lot of logic, but that - at the very least - will solve the ISPICKVAL problem.

Edit: I'm afraid I don't know *why* this is.. in double-checking this I thought I had finally cracked it to be using the different logical operators (like NOT and && side by side in a formula) but that didn't seem to change it in the end.

Edit2: I was right, I think you could express this easier as:

```
rendered="{! Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c != null 
          && Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c == 'High'}"
```

Comment: I had to change it to `rendered="{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c)  && Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c == 'High'), true, false)}` as the `IF()` function threw an invalid arguments exception...but thanks, I will try that

Comment: oh, crickey, yes sorry. I don't think you need the "if" function - I thought I'd removed it (one of my edits was to rebalance my brackets, I must have copied it back in!) try whats in my answer now? ah wait... "now"

Comment: check my second edit.. I reckon that would be how I would do it

Comment: is there anything wrong in my code that would cause the input field `Reason_for_High_Priority` to never be displayed even when "High" is selected in the [I]priority[/i] picklist?

Comment: not unless you have something funky in a controller extension? is it NEVER appearing now then? even when the picklist is set to high..?

Comment: that's right - is the `onchange` event going to cause the rerender? Here is that line of code: `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="MyPanel"/>  `

Comment: Is the `onchange` event fired when the user selects `High`?

Comment: Two things: There's a typo in the first code block (!{ instead of {!). Second, the rendered formula can simply be: `{!Request_for_System_Change__c.Request_Priority__c='High'}`. If it's equal to High, it is not null. Also, Visualforce uses *formula* syntax, meaning `=` is appropriate for comparison.